# How to get Track Id from m4a audio file in swift 5.3

Tags: swift, audio, avfoundation

I am able to get some information from audio track but not track id. Anyone point me to how to get track id? I am using xcode 12.3. Thanks!

```
func getM4aAudioDetails(afile: URL) {

        let song = Song(context: moc)
        let avasset = AVAsset(url: afile as URL) as AVAsset
        let metadata = avasset.metadata(forFormat: AVMetadataFormat.iTunesMetadata)
        let cmetadata = avasset.commonMetadata

        let titleItems = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: metadata, withKey: "©nam", keySpace: AVMetadataKeySpace(rawValue: "itsk"))
        if let data = titleItems.first, let title = data.stringValue {
            song.title = title
        }

        let artistItems = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: metadata, withKey: "©ART", keySpace: AVMetadataKeySpace(rawValue: "itsk"))
        if let data = artistItems.first, let artist = data.stringValue {
            song.artist = artist
        }

        let albumItems = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: metadata, withKey: "©alb", keySpace: AVMetadataKeySpace(rawValue: "itsk"))
        if let data = albumItems.first, let album = data.stringValue {
            song.album = album
        }

        let trackItems = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: metadata, withKey: "trkn", keySpace: AVMetadataKeySpace(rawValue: "itsk"))
        if let data = trackItems.first, let trackString = data.stringValue {
            
            song.track = Int64(trackString)!
            print("Track: \(song.track)")
        }

        let artworkItems = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: cmetadata, filteredByIdentifier: .commonIdentifierArtwork)
        if let artworkItem = artworkItems.first {
            if let imageData = artworkItem.dataValue {
                //let image = NSImage(data: imageData)
                song.artwork = imageData as Data
                //print("image found")
            }
        }
        
        print("song title: \(song.title)")
        print("song artist: \(song.artist)")
        print("song name: \(song.album)")
        print("song track: \(song.track)")
    }
```

Prints: (excerpt)

- song title: Loser
- song artist: Beck
- song name: Mellow Gold
- song track: 0
- song title: Jack-Ass
- song artist: Beck
- song name: Odelay
- song track: 0

Comment: What do you mean by "track ID"?

Comment: means track number.....  trkn/itsk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already got the track number in `trackItems`. However it should be a `dataValue`, not a `stringValue`.

For one of my tracks I see 8 bytes of what looks like 4 16bit big endian integers:

`0x00000008000e0000`

Mine is track 8 of 14, so I guess you want the 2nd integer.

Here's more anecdotal evidence of the above:
https://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2009/Oct/msg00952.html

You could do what you want using this (note the symbols for the `keySpace/key`s):

```
if let trackItem = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: metadata, filteredByIdentifier: .iTunesMetadataTrackNumber).first,
   let data = trackItem.dataValue,
   data.count == 8 {
    let bytes = [UInt8](data)
    let trackNumber = ((Int)(bytes[2]) << 8) | (Int)(bytes[3])
    let totalTracks = ((Int)(bytes[4]) << 8) | (Int)(bytes[5])
    print("trackNumber: \(trackNumber)/\(totalTracks)")
}
```

N.B.: it's different for mp3/ID3 in which case you'll want `id3/TRCK` & it's a `stringValue` containing an integer.

Comment: not sure how to parse trackItems to see what you are seeing. How do I get those values from this code ```   let trackItems = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: metadata, withKey: "trkn", keySpace: AVMetadataKeySpace(rawValue: "itsk"))```
        if let data = trackItems.first, let track = data.dataValue {
            ...

Comment: this works but I do not see total track value. ```        let trackItems = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: metadata, withKey: "trkn", keySpace: AVMetadataKeySpace(rawValue: "itsk"))
        if let data = trackItems.first, let track = data.dataValue {

            song.track = Int64(Int(track[3]))
        }```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Rhythmic Fistman. Very much appreciated!